# How to show message on out of stock products in configurable product. Magento 2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, out-of-stock

I copied the extension from https://github.com/pkarsai/show-out-of-stock-products-magento2 whose code is

> Myweb/ShowOutOfStockProducts/configurableProduct/Helper/Data/Data.php

```
<?php

namespace Myweb\ShowOutOfStockProducts\ConfigurableProduct\Helper\Data;

class Data extends \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Helper\Data
{

    public function getOptions($currentProduct, $allowedProducts)
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $stockRegistry = $objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface');

        $options = [];
        $allowAttributes = $this->getAllowAttributes($currentProduct);

        foreach ($allowedProducts as $product) {
            $productId = $product->getId();

            $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
            $stockitem = $stockRegistry->getStockItem($product->getId(), $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
            if($stockitem->getQty() == 0) continue;

            foreach ($allowAttributes as $attribute) {
                $productAttribute = $attribute->getProductAttribute();
                $productAttributeId = $productAttribute->getId();
                $attributeValue = $product->getData($productAttribute->getAttributeCode());

                $options[$productAttributeId][$attributeValue][] = $productId;
                $options['index'][$productId][$productAttributeId] = $attributeValue;
            }
        }
        return $options;
    }


}
```

> Myweb/ShowOutOfStockProducts/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
    /**
    * @author     Peter Karsai
    * @package    Myweb_ShowOutOfStockProducts
    * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2019 My Web Kft. (http://www.my-web.hu)
    */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Helper\Data"  type="Myweb\ShowOutOfStockProducts\ConfigurableProduct\Helper\Data\Data"/>

    <type name="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable">
        <plugin name="ShowOutOfStockProducts" type="Myweb\ShowOutOfStockProducts\Plugin\ShowOutOfStockProductsPlugin" />
    </type>

    <type name="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute\OptionSelectBuilderInterface">
        <plugin name="Magento_ConfigurableProduct_Plugin_Model_ResourceModel_Attribute_InStockOptionSelectBuilder" disabled="true" />
        <plugin name="ShowAllProductSwatches" type="Myweb\ShowOutOfStockProducts\Plugin\InStockOptionSelectorPlugin"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> Myweb/ShowOutOfStockProducts/Plugin/InStockOptionSelectorPlugin.php

```
<?php

namespace Myweb\ShowOutOfStockProducts\Plugin;

use Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockConfigurationInterface;
use Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\ResourceModel\Stock\Status;
use Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute\OptionSelectBuilderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Select;

class InStockOptionSelectorPlugin extends \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Plugin\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute\InStockOptionSelectBuilder
{
    /**
     * @var StockConfigurationInterface
     */
    private $stockConfiguration;
    /**
     * InStockOptionSelectBuilder constructor
     *
     * @param Status $stockStatusResource
     * @param StockConfigurationInterface $stockConfiguration
     */
    public function __construct(
        Status $stockStatusResource,
        StockConfigurationInterface $stockConfiguration
    ) {
        parent::__construct($stockStatusResource);
        $this->stockConfiguration = $stockConfiguration;
    }
    /**
     * Only Add In stock Filter if Show Out Of Stock Products is set to No
     *
     * @param OptionSelectBuilderInterface $subject
     * @param Select $select
     * @return Select
     */
    public function afterGetSelect(
        OptionSelectBuilderInterface $subject,
        Select $select
    ) {
        if (!$this->stockConfiguration->isShowOutOfStock()) {
            return parent::afterGetSelect($subject, $select);
        }
        return $select;
    }
}
```

> Myweb/ShowOutOfStockProducts/Plugin/ShowOutOfStockProductsPlugin.php

```
<?php

namespace Myweb\ShowOutOfStockProducts\Plugin;

class ShowOutOfStockProductsPlugin {

    /**
     * Get Allowed Products
     *
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product[]
     */
    public function beforeGetAllowProducts(\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable $subject)
    {
        if (!$subject->hasAllowProducts()) {
            $allProducts = $subject->getProduct()->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($subject->getProduct(), null);
            $products = [];
            foreach ($allProducts as $product) {
                if ($product->getStatus() != \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_DISABLED) {
                    $products[] = $product;
                }
            }
            $subject->setAllowProducts($products);
        }
        return [];
    }

}
```

Now the *output* of the plugin is

[image]

now the colors which I Circled is **out of stock** and it is also showing but now I want when the user click on this product then it shows a message *Out Of stock*.. How is it possible??

Answer (score 0):

Change at file

> Myweb/ShowOutOfStockProducts/Plugin/ShowOutOfStockProductsPlugin.php

use **getSalableUsedProducts** instead **getUsedProducts**

```
    <?php

    namespace Myweb\ShowOutOfStockProducts\Plugin;

    class ShowOutOfStockProductsPlugin {

        /**
         * Get Allowed Products
         *
         * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product[]
         */
        public function beforeGetAllowProducts(\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable $subject)
        {
            if (!$subject->hasAllowProducts()) {
               // $allProducts = $subject->getProduct()->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($subject->getProduct(), null);
$allProducts = $subject->getProduct()->getTypeInstance()->getSalableUsedProducts($subject->getProduct(), null);
                $products = [];
                foreach ($allProducts as $product) {
                    if ($product->getStatus() != \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_DISABLED) {
                        $products[] = $product;
                    }
                }
                $subject->setAllowProducts($products);
            }
            return [];
        }

    }
```